# How to tell vulkan memory allocator to use large heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vulkan

I am using VMA to manage my memory. I am trying to allocate a very large buffer (1gb). Printing the  memory heaps from the [physcal device memory properties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties.html) yields 3 heaps with sizes:

```
8589934592
12453559296
257949696
```

Currently my validation layers complaint

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkAllocateMemory-pAllocateInfo-01713 ] Object 0: handle = 0x3541230, name = Logical device: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xe9a2b96f | vkAllocateMemory: attempting to allocate 1073742080 bytes from heap 2,but size of that heap is only 257949696 bytes. The Vulkan spec states: pAllocateInfo->allocationSize must be less than or equal to VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties::memoryHeaps[memindex].size where memindex = VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties::memoryTypes[pAllocateInfo->memoryTypeIndex].heapIndex as returned by vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties for the VkPhysicalDevice that device was created from (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.204.1/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkAllocateMemory-pAllocateInfo-01713)
```

Which seems accurate, heap 2 indeed has not enough memory for this allocation. How do I tell VMA to use heap 1 instead of heap 2?

Comment: So... how are you trying to allocate the memory? I mean, doesn't VMA have some way of controlling which heap to allocate from?

Comment: "*2 heaps with sizes:*" That's 3 sizes.

Comment: What `VmaMemoryUsage` are you providing?

Comment: @krOoze CPUT_TO_GPU

Comment: @Makogan [Then you asked for that small memory heap](https://gpuopen-librariesandsdks.github.io/VulkanMemoryAllocator/html/group__group__alloc.html#ggaa5846affa1e9da3800e3e78fae2305cca9066b52c5a7079bb74a69aaf8b92ff67)...